# how to add files to jars META-INF

Tags: java, jar

i want to create a jar file in which i want to place some file in the META-INF folder of the jar file.is it possible ? .i know how to create a jar file but clueless about how to put files inside META-INF

below is my desired jar files META-INF directory

META-INF > somefolder > somefile

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
jar uf jarfile.jar META-INF/somefolder/somefile
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename the `.jar`-file to something ending with `.zip`, open it with an appropriate program, change what you want to change, save it and rename it back to `.jar`. Jarfiles are Zipfiles.

Answer (score 2):

From the [jar documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html):

> Updates an existing file jarfile (when
>   f is specified) by adding to it files
>   and directories specified by
>   inputfiles. For example: jar uf
>   foo.jar foo.class

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the META-INF folder already when you create the jar from the source. Just put your files there before making the jar.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a `META-INF` directory among the .class-files that you want to be included in the jar. Put whatever you want in this `META-INF` directory, and it will be included in the compiled jar-file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to create a JAR with a custom folder `somefolder` under `META-INF`:

```
mkdir META-INF
cp -a somefolder META-INF
jar cvf jarfile.jar META-INF/
```