# eclipse *.jar export does not contain all provider configuration files of subprojects in META-INF/services

Tags: java, jar, export, classloader, meta-inf

I'm trying to export a Java project with "Export as Runnable JAR" in eclipse, that amongst others contains two project references that each contain a META-INF folder in their src/ folder (see image).

Now, my problem is, when I export the jar and look into its META-INF/services folder, I'm missing the content of the META-INF folder from project "DataBrowser" (namely "net.sytes.botg.browser.DataBrowser".

I looked into issues like [how to add files to jars META-INF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079675/how-to-add-files-to-jars-meta-inf), where a manual solution is to add the missing file to the META-INF folder after jar creation. But, I'm looking for a solution within eclipse, that makes sure both META-INF Folders are merged into one in the exported jar, or at least exports both META-INF folders, somewhere where they can be found by the service loader (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

[META-INF Export Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yXcp.png)

Thanks for any help!